# Adding WatchOS App to a existing Flutter App

Tags: swift, flutter, xcode, watchos, huawei-developers

i am trying to add my watchOs app to my existing flutter app which can be used also for huawei devices.
However, when i try to build the merged project i got this error.

Error1: Framework AGConnectCore not found.

What i learnt while i was researching this issue watchos 2.0 is codependent from iphone's framework anymore. So I added the framework to my watchapp extension. Then i got this error.

Error2: /Users/kubilaykitapcioglu/Projects/port-mobile-app/ios/Pods/AGConnectCore/AGConnectCore.xcframework:1:1 While building for watchOS Simulator, no library for this platform was found in '/Users/kubilaykitapcioglu/Projects/port-mobile-app/ios/Pods/AGConnectCore/AGConnectCore.xcframework'.

Can anyone help me with this

Thank you.

I tried to add my watchos app to my existing flutter app